# Google disallowing Ad because of "Unwanted Software". Could this be Blazor DLLs? How to solve?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, google-search-console

I have a functioning website with a blazor client side component (webassembly/WASM). I then tried to google advertise for the site, but it was rejected for Unwanted Software.  I looked at my site, and within wwwroot there is of course a _bin_framework directory with dlls in that get downloaded to client browser.

Could this be the problem? What might be a workaround?
Alternatively, does anyone have examples of blazor WASM sites which are successful targets for google ads that might demonstrate that the Blazor DLLs are not the problem and something else might be?

(In fact any general advice on how to deal with rejection by google for unwanted software much appreciated!)

Comment: Hello, did you found anything? I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the advice from the Blazor team about renaming the .DLL extensions after the app is published:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#change-the-filename-extension-of-dll-files

Comment: Doesn't work - also tried modifying the blazor bootloader and forcing to use the brotli compressed objects. Still rejected